# Error generated during running of model. (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When i run my model (fit a model) got below error and it stops a kernel.. Please guide me for the same.

I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance‑critical operations: AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 1661 MB memory: ‑> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1661 MB memory: ‑> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6

I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8303

I have Nvidia Geforce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU.

NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU

Driver version: 31.0.15.1640
Driver date: 06-06-2022
DirectX version: 12 (FL 12.1)
Physical location: PCI bus 1, device 0, function 0

Utilization 0%
Dedicated GPU memory 0.8/4.0 GB
Shared GPU memory 0.1/6.9 GB
GPU Memory 0.9/10.9 GB

Tensorflow version - 2.9.1
Cuda - cuda_11.5.0_496.13
Cuddn - cudnn_8.3.3.40
Windows 11

Comment: Hi @Bhavin Mehta, as per the [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu), Tensorflow 2.9 is compatible with `CUDA 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.1`. Please downgrade the versions of CUDA and cuDNN and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!